# Unidentified Correlation Formula

Tags: correlation, definition

I got a formula of correlation in the book but I know it is not the Pearson Correlation formula. What I found is

$$r_{xy}=\frac{N\sum xy-(\sum x)(\sum y)}{[N\sum x^2-(\sum x)^2][N\sum y^2-(\sum y)^2]}$$

where N = number of sample, x is the first variable and y is the other variable. What I know with the Pearson correlation. It should be

$$
r=\frac{N\sum xy-(\sum x)(\sum y)}{\sqrt{[N\sum x^2-(\sum x)^2][N\sum y^2-(\sum y)^2]}}
$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#For_a_sample - wiki pages on simple formulas are pretty accurate, just use them

Comment: Where did you find your top formula? What makes you think it's not simply an error?

Comment: From a book in our library. I can't remember the title but it seems like basic statistics for nursing and engineering student